Closed One Tap reappears on subdomain with FedCM
When I switch to FedCM, cooldown mechanism seems to be broken and 'one tap' is shown even on subdomains even after closing it on parent domain. 
It is working when FedCM is switched off. 
Previously that behaviour was enabled through state_cookie_domain but I can't find anything similar to FedCM that would allow to respect user's choice and not show 'one tap' after closing it.
